# Show a spinner dialog while a long running async task is running

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I am doing a remote http call from an AsyncTask and I would like to show a spinner progress dialog.
I did this:

```
public class LongRunningTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog prog;
    public LongRunningTask(){}

    public LongRunningTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        prog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        prog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        prog.setTitle("bla");
        prog.setMessage("BLABLA");
        prog.setIndeterminate(false);
        prog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        prog.show();
       }
....
}
```

And from my fragment I do:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new LongRunningTask(getActivity()).execute();   
    }
}).run();
```

And my application crashes (without any stack trace...)
How can I implement this?

Comment: your `LongRunningTask` has no constructor that takes a Context object as parameter. More than crashing your code is not compiling

Comment: @Blackbelt:I only pasted the pre/post execute as the constructor just does `this.ctx = ctx`

Comment: I think you are not allowed to run an asynctask from a thread != Ui thread.

Comment: `AsyncTask` should be created on `UI Thread` and you creates it on another thread.

Comment: @Blackbelt:Well the http call works even if my code is not how someone who knows android would do it (I am newbie).

Comment: and why to create a new thread when the `AsyncTask` has it own thread.

Comment: @MoshErsan:I was not sure if the UI thread would be blocked or not

Comment: try to call `new LongRunningTask(getActivity()).execute();` without the `new thread....`

Comment: please read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: they declare a Handler to call onPre/onPost execute on the UI thread, and they probably need the main thread looper as argument for the handler. Not sure though. Just speculating

Comment: @MoshErsan, Blackbelt: Removing the thread it works yes. But the dialog is displayed very late almost just before showing the results. While I want a spinner to be displayed (not progressbar) while the running task is executing

Comment: Nothing crash without a stacktrace. Are you checking your logcat properly?